# How do I combine a 1D array to the end of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following 2 arrays A and B:

```
A
array([[ 2., 19.,  8.],
       [ 3.,  7., 15.]])
```

```
B
array([429., 283.])
```

```
A.shape
(2, 3)
```

```
B.shape
(2,)
```

What is the best way to combine the 1D array B to the end of the 2D array A, such that

```
array([[ 2., 19.,  8., 429.],
       [ 3.,  7., 15., 283.]])
```

Comment: Make B` a (2,1), and `concatenate` on the right axis